# how to set Maven home and path variables in windows7 using command prompt?

Tags: maven, path, command-prompt, setting

I just downloaded maven from apache website and I cannot set the variables through my system settings and I want to know the command to set the maven home and path variables , I have already installed java .So any one could tell me the commands for setting maven home and path variables

Answer (score 1):

On the Maven download page there is an instruction on how to do this: http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi#Windows_2000XP

(If you are running a Unix based system, the instructions are right below the Windows system instructions)

Comment: Thank you for your reply but as I already posted I need command Prompt codes like set M2_HOME... because I cannot go to my system properties

Comment: What operating system?